# Dictionary in C

Tags: c, dictionary, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a pretty simple Dictionary in C. I was thinking about using a linked list. I saw this implementation online:
https://gist.github.com/kgabis/3141664 (I tried to post the code here but It did not let me).

It seems kinda like what I had in mind except my value has to be an integer. Also in my own "get" function I didn't make my list point to the tail after returning the value, Did I do wrong?

My question is: Is it considered a good implementation code for a Dictionary? 
My own code is a bit different since I wanted to be able to print the Dictionary (having a hard time to figure how should I print my key-value pair!)
and I also want to be able to make a Dictionary out of keys array and values array!

I'm stuck on those for few days now, Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Comment: `a good implementation code` - you didn't show any code. What exactly is your question? What exactly are you having problem with? Please read [how to ask a good question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [what topics can you ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Maybe your question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Stackoverflow is not a "forum" to talk about some code someone wrote - it's a forum for specific programming problems and how to solve them.

Comment: My questions are: How do I print the dictionary assuming it is like the code that I linked? and how can I make a Dictionary like that when I'm given 2 arrays (keys array and values array, both are the same size

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html or https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html

Comment: I'm not allowed to use hash tables yet.. I could post my own code but it is very similar to the one that I have found actually and the system in this forum didn't let me post my own code for some reason!

Comment: You can include fully runnable minimal examples or code snippets in the text of your question (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Although not a *code review* site. "Not allowed to use hash tables", if you have special requirements be sure to include in questions, although Id say definitely worth learning extra things like hash tables yourself if not included in a specific course.

Comment: I will ask a new question soon with my own code! I know it is worth learning and I do read a lot by myself, I read about it as well. BTW sorry if my English is bad it is not my mother tongue and I'm 14 actually haha

Comment: How long is your code? It's possible that it goes over the character limit, in which case you'll need to make it shorter.

Comment: it is 108 lines in VS atm

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to implement a pretty simple Dictionary in C. I was thinking about using a linked list. [...] Is it considered a good implementation code for a Dictionary?

**No**, most definitely not. The main purpose of a dictionary-like structure is to provide very fast insertion, deletion and lookup of values (given a key), which usually mans constant time complexity (`O(1)`). A linked list would have linear insertion and lookup time complexity, meaning that to access a value knowing its key, `O(n)` operations would be needed, where `n` is the number of values already present in the list. This would basically have the same performance as a simple unsorted array, nullifying the utility of the structure. The de-facto standard way of implementing such a structure is to use an [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which permits, given a reasonably good hashing function and collision resolution strategy, access to data in constant time.

See also: [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: I have not learned about hash tables yet actually. I have learned about linked list, stack, array, bin trees.. Also could you please help me with the print and vreate from array functions?

Comment: @static Stack Overflow is not a support website, I cannot help you with that, I'm sorry. You should try implementing those functions yourself and ask another question here if you get stuck with a particular problem.

Comment: @static Plenty of resources around on hash tables. Other possible options depending on requirements is a sorted array (binary search lookup) or various tree structures. If you want to implement such things and have some code, but some issues with *your code*, then that can be further questions.

Comment: I tried to post my own code here and show you my actual problems but It did not let me post it for some reason..

Comment: @static I'm not sure what that means. You can very easily copy-paste the relevant code into a question. Try asking another more detailed question and make sure that your code provides a [mcve]. You can refer to [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.

Comment: Somehow you managed to write a good informative answer to an off-topic question. +1!